# Continuous for future arrangement

Tags: continuous

> I was supposed to **be getting** copies. I wrote the label when these were first announced asking for 30 something copies and he wrote back that he would contact me when they were ready.

Did the author choose to use continuous because it was a future thing planned before? I think so after reading the great answer for [Is "supposed to play" semantically different from "supposed to be playing"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122918/is-supposed-to-play-semantically-different-from-supposed-to-be-playing)

Comment: I guess it's one of those unanswerable questions where both "to be getting" and "to get" are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i'm aware: yes, pretty much.  An alternative would be:

> I was supposed to get copies.

But this isn't exactly the same.  While this sentence, like the one you've posted in your question, implies a promise made sometime in the past, the use of "get" over "be getting" means that the speaker should have received the copies in the past; the use of "be getting," on the other hand, means that the speaker should be receiving copies in the present.